# Get field value from Array based on another field data matching

Tags: node.js

Below is my sample JSON object. I want to get the `'title'` value based
 on the longitude value. I have multiple(20-30) longitudes to get the titles, so I don't want to loop through those many times:

```
{
    items:[ 
        { 
            longitude:-72.897668, 
            latitude:40.453576, 
            title:52 street
        },
        { 
            longitude:-71.897668, 
            latitude:41.453576, 
            title:5th Ave 
        } 
    ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to get value without using for-loops.

Comment: If you want to find something in an array, did you consider using `Array#find`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something linke [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)?

```
function filterByLongitude(element) {
    var expected = -72.897668
    return element.longitude === expected;
}

var items = [{
    longitude:-72.897668,
    latitude:40.453576, 
    title:'52 street'
  }, {
    longitude:-71.897668,
    latitude:41.453576,
    title: '5th Ave'
  }];

var match = items.filter(filterByLongitude);
console.log(match[0].title); // 52 street
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the quick response. I have tried your code locally its working fine. But when I moved to Oracle MCS (internally using node js to develop services) its failing with error "Custom Code Problem in oracleMobile.rest callback: TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined". And i also tried filter but no luck.

Comment: Make sure that a) `items` is defined and b) the variable `items` is of type `array` (otherwise you have no filter method in the prototype).